# Odd getattr() behaviour with class property in the default

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr

Here I expected that all 4 IDs will be the same, however it seems that when I pass class property to the `default` attribute of the `getattr`, it simply skips the attribute lookup and always return the `default`:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, May 11 2018, 04:00:52) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from datetime import datetime
   ...: 
   ...: class my_cls(object):
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def _id(self):
   ...:         self._cid = datetime.now().isoformat()
   ...:         return self._cid
   ...: 
   ...:     def get_id(self):
   ...:         return getattr(self, '_cid', self._id)
   ...: 
   ...: cls = my_cls()
   ...: print('Init ID:', cls._id)
   ...: print('Still OK:', getattr(cls, '_cid', False))
   ...: print('WRONG:', getattr(cls, '_cid', cls._id))
   ...: print('WRONG:', cls.get_id())
   ...: 
   ...: 
Init ID: 2018-06-17T12:45:20.409601
Still OK: 2018-06-17T12:45:20.409601
WRONG: 2018-06-17T12:45:20.409804
WRONG: 2018-06-17T12:45:20.409849
```

Is that expected and/or documented behaviour? Why is `getattr` doing what it's doing?

Comment: Don't make properties with side effects and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `getattr`, it's your code accessing `cls._id` before calling `getattr`.

In Python, before a function is called, all its arguments are evaluated. In particular, in `getattr(cls, '_cid', cls._id)` subexpression `cls._id` is  evaluated. In order to do so, `_id` property is accessed, which updates `_cid`. `getattr` is called afterwards and returns the updated value.

Comment: Note: your quote `getattr(cls, '_cid_', cls._id)` is incorrect, should be `getattr(cls, '_cid', cls._id)`.

Comment: @NarūnasK thanks, fixed.